# Is it worth upgrading to the latest version of CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, upgrade

I am about 2 minor revisions behind.

Answer (score 2):

I'm one of those guys who always upgrade stuff. But have a look at the official [changelog](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html) and see if the many bugfixes and new features are interesting enough to you.

I noticed 1.7.0 is out, and I'm definetly going to upgrade. But I need to test my applications after upgrading, since changes *could* break existing code.

Answer (score 1):

If there is some new feature you would find useful, or it fixes some bug that has been annoying you, absolutely. If you are only to minor versions behind, there probably isn't much reason to upgrade.

Check the [changelog](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html), if there's something that interests you, then upgrade.

I suppose the "if it's not broken, don't fix it" saying still applies, but if it's a small personal project, why not play around with the new shinier version?

Answer (score 0):

I always watch out for the latest version especially for a pet project of mine. There was just a problem with my upgrade to 1.7.0 which broke my authentication processes using CI sessions.

I ended up building my own Auth library using Native sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded, there's some cool new features like with the Form Validation class, you no longer have 2 separate lines for rules and fields.

Here are some of the changes in the Validation class, for example:

#### The first is anywhere you load the validation library.

Old/deprecated method: $this->load->library(’validation’);

New method: $this->load->library(’form_validation’);

#### You need to also change your fields and rule declarations:

Old/deprecated method: $rules['name'] = “trim|required|max_length[100]“; $fields['name'] = “your name”;

New method: $this->form_validation->set_rules(’name’, ‘your name’, ‘trim|required|max_length[100]‘);

#### And finally, change conditional checks:

Old/deprecated method: if ($this->validation->run() == TRUE) {}

New method: if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {}